# Convert to string nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography

`0xc4115 0x4cf8`
Im not sure what data type this is so my question would be:

What data type is this and how can I convert it to something more manageable using NODE.JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can convert Hexadecimal to Decimal by this

```
let hex_num = "0xc4115";
console.log(Number(hex_num)); #803093
```

Answer (score 0):

In general you have the format 0x for hexadecimal, 0b for binary and 0 for octal. All this represent Numbers. JavaScript converts to decimal all of this types automatically. In case you want to do it yourself, you can use parseInt(number,base).